# Color-correcting super 8 video from 1975

Tags: video-editor, color-correction

I've got some super 8 video from 1975 that I had digitized, and the color is pretty wonky (here's a screen capture, we're actually skiing down a snow-covered road)

[image]

I assume it's the film itself and not the digitization, but now what?  I don't have a professional editing setup, but I do have Sony Vegas Movie Studio HD Platinum 11.0 which has a color corrector filter but I have no idea how to set the color corrector to improve the video.

[image: color corrector]

How do I figure out what settings to use?  Will this tool do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Play with color corrector controls. Use "High" control to adjust snow to the tint you prefer, use "Mid" and "Low" to adjust face and hat. As you see, I moved "High" and "Mid" to the green/blue zone to offset red tint, but I moved "Low" to the red/yellow zone because this way the face and the hat looks better to me.

Or you can convert it to black and white with the Black and White effect.